# SQL count occurrence by column

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-like

After some research I haven't found what I need and I thought I'll ask here. I'm currently trying to develop a advanced search mode for a application and I'm stuck with my task. Maybe you can help me. So imagine I have the following table:

```
ID | Name    | Surname
1  | John    | Mim
2  | Johnny  | Crazy
3  | Mike    | Something
4  | Milk    | Milk
5  | Peter   | IDontknow
6  | Mitch   | SomeName
```

Then in my frontend, there's one input field. The input of that field will go trough the query in that way:

```
SELECT name, surname FROM people WHERE name LIKE 'input%' OR surname LIKE 'input%'
```

Now lets say my input is "Mi", so I'll have 3 columns match in the "name" column, and 2 in the surname. And that's what I'm looking for.

A count which ouputs the following:

```
Column  | Count
Name    | 3
Surname | 2
```

Is there a way to achieve this in only one query?

**What I've tried so far:**
I actually created the table above on my localhost in my database and tried different queries. Tried with `SELECT count(name), count(surname)`, but that would output 3 for both counts. So I'm not even sure if that's possible in only one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `union all`

```
SELECT 'name' as col, count(name) as cnt FROM people WHERE name LIKE 'input%' 
union all
SELECT 'surname', count(surname) FROM people WHERE  surname LIKE 'input%'
```

Comment: You my friend, are a true hero.

Answer (score 1):

make customize group using case when

```
SELECT (case when name  LIKE 'input%' then 'name'
          else 'surname' end) as Column, count(*) as cnt
    FROM people WHERE name LIKE 'input%' OR surname LIKE 'input%'
    group by Column
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT "Name" as Column, count(*) as Count FROM people WHERE name LIKE 'mi%'
UNION
SELECT "Surname" as Column, count(*) as Count FROM people WHERE surname LIKE 'mi%'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql booleans are evaluated as 1 or 0, so you can do this:

```
select 'Name' Column, sum(name LIKE 'input%') Count from people
union all
select 'Surname', sum(surname LIKE 'input%') from people
```

For Mysql 8.0+ you can avoid the double scan of the table with a CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select 
    sum(name LIKE 'input%') namecounter, 
    sum(surname LIKE 'input%') surnamecounter
  from people
)
select 'Name' Column, namecounter Count from cte
union all
select 'Surname', surnamecounter from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution without `UNION[ ALL]` of the `people` table:

```
SELECT
  CASE cj.x WHEN 1 THEN 'Name' ELSE 'Surname' END AS `Column`,
  CASE cj.x
    WHEN 1 THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Name LIKE concat(@input, '%') THEN 1 end)
    ELSE COUNT(CASE WHEN Surname LIKE concat(@input, '%') THEN 1 END)
  END `Count`
FROM people CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS cj
WHERE Name LIKE concat(@input, '%') OR Surname LIKE concat(@input, '%')
GROUP BY cj.x;
```

**Output for the `Mi` input:**

```
| Column  | Count |
+---------+-------+
| Name    |     3 |
| Surname |     2 |
```

Test it online with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7312b2/3).